# WiX InstanceTransforms element produces unresolved reference

Tags: wix, setup-project, windows-installer, instance-transform

I am trying to create a multi-instance setup and followed this question and answers to make it:

[Use WIX to install side by side versions of the same IIS site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214540/use-wix-to-install-side-by-side-versions-of-the-same-iis-site)

So I inserted this to my product.wix file

```
<InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
  <Instance Id="I01" ProductCode="{68E8345E-0B22-479C-B7A5-7D1B3DC2F835}" ProductName="My Product 01"/>
  <Instance Id="I02" ProductCode="{A0E37B8D-12AB-42A0-8F11-9CB08F54B9DE}" ProductName="My Product 02"/>
</InstanceTransforms>
```

However, when I build my setup project, I get this error:

> Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:INSTANCEID' in section
>   'Product:{38EEE9BE-86BF-49FB-813B-953DD945575E}'.

Where 38EEE9BE-86BF-49FB-813B-953DD945575E is my main Product Id.
I could not find any reference to this error in the InstanceTransform scope. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:
The first thing I tried when I got this error was of course creating a property inside my product with that is called INSTANCEID and some value. However, the error persisted.

I added the Yan's code from his comment below and it compiled. I am not sure what was wrong with my property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `Property` element with the Id of your InstanceTranforms/@Property value.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev, this is the way it is defined in the sample I reference in that blog post: `<Property Id="INSTANCEID" Value="I00">
 <RegistrySearch Id="InstanceIdSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MultiInstanceTest\[ProductCode]" Name="InstanceId" Type="raw" /> </Property>`

Comment: I am lost. I posted a screenshot to illustrate the problem. It has the property declaration and it still throws the build error.

Comment: Which build error? If you fix your Property element by removing "Something," do you still get the "unresolved reference" error?

Comment: I was sure I tried that. I copies the code of Yan and it worked.